# Request to find in msql db the closest element in time

Tags: mysql, date, time

I'm trying to get the picture time the closest to actual time. 
I've tried to improve my request but i'm stuck on my WHERE clause :

*last syntax try : *
WHERE TIME(heure_pdv) BETWEEN SUBTIME(CURTIME(),INTERVAL 2 HOUR) AND ADDTIME(CURTIME(),INTERVAL 2 HOUR)

then i get an error :
ERREUR MYSQL numéro:1064 Type de cette erreur: You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Where an i wrong ?
Thanks

nb : the heure_pdv column is a time type.

that request seems to works but i'm not sure it's correctely written (especially the "curtime()+8" :

```
                "SELECT 
                fichier,
                date_pdv,
                commune,
                pays,
                ib_medias.cover, 
                heure_pdv, 
                ib_series.titre AS titre_serie,
                ib_series.public AS aff_serie, 
                ib_series.id AS id_serie, 
                serie AS id_serie,
                ABS(TIMEDIFF(heure_pdv,CURTIME())) as differ ,
                ib_medias.titre AS titre_image 
                FROM ib_medias LEFT OUTER JOIN ib_series
                ON ib_medias.serie = ib_series.id 
                WHERE HOUR(heure_pdv)BETWEEN HOUR(CURTIME()) AND HOUR(CURTIME()+8)
                    AND ib_medias.site_cover > 0 
                    ORDER BY differ
                    LIMIT 0, 1";
```

Comment: Can you add an example?

Comment: if the present time is 11:22 pm i want to find a picture that was taken for example at 11:20 or 11:25 at this time the 11:22 picture would be chosen one minute later it would be the 11:25 one

Comment: And the column type is `timestamp` I believe?

Comment: Nope it's a TIME type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your contribution all I post the best working request :

```
    SELECT fichier,
                date_pdv,
                commune,
                pays,
                ib_medias.cover, 
                heure_pdv, 
                ib_series.titre AS titre_serie,
                ib_series.public AS aff_serie, 
                ib_series.id AS id_serie, 
                serie AS id_serie,
                ABS(TIMEDIFF(heure_pdv,CURTIME())) as differ ,
                ib_medias.titre AS titre_image 
                FROM ib_medias LEFT OUTER JOIN ib_series
                ON ib_medias.serie = ib_series.id 
                WHERE ib_medias.site_cover > 0 
                ORDER BY differ
                LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

addtime is a function used to subtract one datetime value from another.
check link: http://w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-subtime-function.php

U should use date_add :

```
    select * 
from photo 
where TIME(heure_pdv) BETWEEN date_add(CURTIME(),INTERVAL -2 HOUR) AND date_add(CURTIME(),INTERVAL 2 HOUR)
```

Comment: No more error mesage but no values are returned. heure_pdv is a time column. I have the date on another one because i knew i would search specifically on time.

Comment: where HOUR(heure_pdv)BETWEEN HOUR(date_add(CURTIME(),INTERVAL -2 HOUR)) AND HOUR(date_add(CURTIME(),INTERVAL 2 HOUR))... Still nothing

Comment: with a date_add shouldn't i extract the time to match with "heure_pdv"?

Comment: Works fine in mysql, what version are you working on?

Answer (score 0):

So, you have to order the records (in `ascending`) by difference between current time and time the picture was taken, try the below query:

```
SELECT 
fichier,
date_pdv,
commune,
pays,
ib_medias.cover, 
heure_pdv, 
ib_series.titre AS titre_serie,
ib_series.public AS aff_serie, 
ib_series.id AS id_serie, 
serie AS id_serie,
ABS(TIMEDIFF(heure_pdv,CURTIME())) as differ ,
ib_medias.titre AS titre_image 
FROM ib_medias LEFT OUTER JOIN ib_series
ON ib_medias.serie = ib_series.id 
WHERE ib_medias.site_cover > 0 
ORDER BY ABS(CURTIME() - heure_pdv)
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Looks like it works fine. In fact my request had to be much more simpler than the one i worked on. Thanks !

Comment: The order by clause isn't working fine . Better Result with ORDER BY differ

Comment: Okay, I guess it's because of the way `TIMEDIFF` and subtraction works.

Comment: Yes, when i do a limit 10 with your request the order of picture isn't accurate. It gives me a sort for the current hour then a sort for the next hour but doesn't respect time difference. Thanks whatever you put me on the right way :)